# Intermediate Cloud formation template with values filled from Dynamic CFT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Would like know if CFT API's or logs from Cloudtrail can provide any intermediate CFT before or while creating the resources. When I mean intermediate CFT(s) , We know the CFT can be kind of dynamic in the form of parameters /condition/mappings/functions those are to be evaluated at run time. I would like to know if this CFT can generate the processed CFT (with all the processed rules/parameters from input/functions...) as though it looks like static for the resource creation process. This approach really helps us in validating the real CFT that is going to be executed with all the values replaced. I'm just looking for the another CFT API. something like ,

**`String staticCFT = cftClient.getActualCFT("cft_location\cft.json","parameters"...);`**

If this feature is available , it really saves time and don't have to wait until all the resources are created with wrong values because of wrong logic in CFT.

Answer (score 0):

What you can actually create is what I call a "dummy template". I use it at work as a stand-in to an actual template with real resources which would take time to execute. The dummy template has only one resource which does not actually do anything. I use a CustomResource to invoke a "HelloWorld" Lambda function. This is to get around the restriction that a CFT must have at least one resource. The template also has a bunch of parameters and all those parameters are simply supplied directly to the Outputs section. The execution of this template will hardly take a few seconds and based on the parameters and outputs, you can figure out whether your top-level template is passing in the expected values of the parameters. You can invoke the dummy template from within the top-level template.